# Import ace code editor into webpack, es6, typescript project

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, web-component

I'm trying to build a web component that will host the ace editor. The trouble is that I don't find enough information on how to import the module and set the types. The code bellow was working just fine using simple `<script>` tags and global vars.

So far this is what I have:

```
npm install ace-code-editor --save
npm install @types/ace --save-dev
```

**code-editor.cmp.ts**

```
// Error: [ts] File '.../node_modules/@types/ace/index.d.ts' is not a module.
import * as ace from 'ace';

export class CodeEditorCmp extends HTMLElement {

    // DOM
    private editor: AceAjax;  // How do I import the type. What type to use?

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.initCodeEditor();
    }

    initCodeEditor(){

        this.editor = ace.edit("editor-vsc");

        // How do I import the editor themes?
        this.editor.setTheme("ace/theme/xcode"); 

        // How do I import the editor modes?
        var JavaScriptMode = ace.require("ace/mode/html").Mode; 

        this.editor.session.setMode(new JavaScriptMode());
        this.editor.getSession().setTabSize(4);
        this.editor.getSession().setUseSoftTabs(true);
        this.editor.getSession().setUseWrapMode(true);
        this.editor.setAutoScrollEditorIntoView(true);

        // Update document
        this.editor.getSession().on('change', this.onEditorChange);
    }

    onEditorChange(){
    }

}

require('./code-editor.cmp.scss');
window.customElements.define('editor-vsc', CodeEditorCmp);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For those who don't want to use the brace module,  I saw that my issue was that I was importing the wrong version of ace.  Once installed, make sure to import from `src-noconflict`.  The noconflict version uses ace.require which seems to play a lot more nicely than the other iterations that use require.

I would suggest that you do the following:

```
npm install ace-builds --save
npm install @types/ace --save-dev
```

Afterwards in your file just import the noconflict like below:

`import * as ace from 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace';`

This will result in a variable `ace` being defined.  You will then be able to reference methods and properties of ace as normal, such as `ace.edit()`

You can get more information about the different versions of ace [check out the git page.](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds)

Comment: I have successfully installed the package:
`"@types/ace": "^0.0.48",`
but still when I try to import:
`import * as ace from 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace';`
I get the following error message:
Could not find a declaration file for module 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace'. '/.../node_modules/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/ace-builds` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace';`ts.

Any workaround for this?? I'm using node 18.x and Typescript

Answer (score 8):

After a lot of digging I managed to find [brace](https://github.com/thlorenz/brace) module. It's a browserify wrapper for ace. Fortunately it works straight away with webpack. No need to use separate types, they come prepackaged.

```
import * as ace from 'brace';
import 'brace/mode/javascript';
import 'brace/theme/monokai';

export class CodeEditorCmp extends HTMLElement {

    private editor: ace.Editor;

    initCodeEditor(){
        this.editor = ace.edit('javascript-editor');
        this.editor.getSession().setMode('ace/mode/javascript');
        this.editor.setTheme('ace/theme/monokai');
        //...
    }

    //...
}
```